# Scan only certain types of barcodes with Cordova BarcodeScanner

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, cordova-plugins

I'm experimenting with the [Cordova/Phonegap BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) and experience a strange behavior when scanning a barcode from a certain angle.

Assuming I have a Barcode of type `EAN_13` and scan it perfectly straight I get the right result, but when I turn the camera and try to scan from a worse angle the result doesn't fit anymore. I found out that the type of the scanned result is now `EAN_8` or even `UPC_E`.

My question is, can I tell my barcode scanner only to scan barcodes of a certain type so that getting a wrong result doesn't happen? As far as I tested this, that behavior doesn't occur when using barcode scanner apps from the app store. Here either I get the right result or no code is recognized at all.

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

Answer (score 1):

The scan function takes a third parameter, a config object, which contains values that are sent to ZXing as extras. ZXing provides two options for enabling/disabling barcode formats: `SCAN_MODE` and `SCAN_FORMATS`, where SCAN_MODE is a preset for common combinations of formats.

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
   function (result) {
       alert("We got a barcode\n" +
             "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
             "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
             "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
   }, 
   function (error) {
       alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
   },
   {
       // "SCAN_MODE": "PRODUCT_MODE",
       "SCAN_FORMATS": "EAN_13"
   }
);
```

You can use either `SCAN_MODE` or `SCAN_FORMATS`, but not both. In your case, you can only enable `EAN_13` to prevent the false positive matches.

Comment: thank you - this seems like the way i was looking for, but i can't get it to work with your code. when setting `SCAN_FORMATS` to `EAN_13` i'm still getting results for `EAN_8` codes and others. is there a documentation available showing how to to use the config object properly and which values are allowed?

Comment: What platform are you running your Cordova app on?

Comment: currently running ios 8.3 on an iphone 6, have not tested on an android device yet

Comment: Ah, the config object might be Android only. I just took a brief look at the iOS code for the Barcode Scanner plugin and it seems to use that third parameter for passing a custom overlay instead.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I just tested on an Android 5.1.1 device and still get results for `EAN_13` and `EAN_8` barcodes when calling the scanner with the following:  `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, error, {"SCAN_FORMATS": "EAN_13"});`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? EAN_13 codes are being read as UPC_A